# ValueError: could not convert string to float after converting features to integers for decision tree

Tags: python, decision-tree

I converted my dataset features into integers using the following code:

```
car_df = pd.DataFrame({'Integer Feature': [0,1,2,3,4,5], 
                  'Categorical Feature': ['buying', 'maint', 'doors', 'persons', 'lug_boot', 'safety']})
```

This worked. Now, I am trying to create a decision tree and used the following code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier() 
dtree.fit(car_df, y)
```

However, I get an error stating: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'buying'`
'Buying' is the first categorical feature in the dataset. There are six categorical features.

I thought that would not have been an issue since I converted the features to integers. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: You are getting the error because the "Categorical Feature" column in the car_df dataframe contains strings.  That feature has not been converted to integer type,  based on the code you show here.  "Buying" is not a feature, it is a value in the car_df dataframe.  What exactly are you trying to do when creating the car_df dataframe, because that does not look like a conversion.  You are just creating a dataframe.

Comment: @AlexK Thank you for your comment, I appreciate it--that makes sense.  My dataset features are buying, maint, doors, persons, lug_boot, and safety. (doors and persons have integer values) For Integer Feature, am I only listing the corresponding features that have integer values (so doors and persons)? I tried that, but then the arrays are not the same length. Ultimately, I am trying to create a dataframe where the categorical features are converted to integers. I was using code from my text book as a template.

Comment: It's still not clear what the purpose of your car_df dataframe is.  I suspect that you have another table/dataframe with actual values of these features that you want to pass to the .fit() method.  So why are you creating this car_df dataframe and using that in the .fit() method?

Comment: I have been instructed to convert the categorical features to integers using get_dummies. The example I have in my book uses a dataframe to do that. When I try to use my original data frame for the .fit() method, I have the same error. Ultimately, I am trying to create a decision tree.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  You can run `pd.__version__` to check.

Comment: I provided an answer on dummy conversion without utilizing the extra dataframe that you are creating.  If you need to use this extra dataframe, perhaps you can can edit your question and add the example you are trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled this cars dataset so I have a better idea of its contents.  Based on the documentation, here are the columns with possible values:

```
  buying       v-high, high, med, low
  maint        v-high, high, med, low
  doors        2, 3, 4, 5-more
  persons      2, 4, more
  lug_boot     small, med, big
  safety       low, med, high
```

So all of these columns can contain strings and they all need to be converted to numeric type before you can pass the dataset to your model's `fit()` method.

Per Pandas documentation of the `get_dummies()` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html:

Once you have your original dataset in a dataframe (call it `df`), you can pass it to the `.get_dummies()` method like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

This code will convert any columns with object or category dtype to integer dummies and will name each new column using the {original column name}_{original value} convention.

Comment: I am so sorry to be just now getting back to you--thank you for your help! This worked for me!

Comment: @GEB If my answer was helpful, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/295067) it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks.